# Evaluate the integral of $\int \frac{1}{\left(\ln x\right)^{\ln x}}dx$

Tags: integration

I recently completed a quiz for my Calc 2 class and I could not find the answer to this integral:

$$ \int \frac{1}{\left(\ln x\right)^{\ln x}}dx $$

I tried to use integration by parts and was able to get to: $$ \int \frac{1}{\left(\ln x\right)^{\ln x}}dx\:=\:\frac{n}{\left(\ln x\right)^{\ln x}}\:+\int \:\frac{\ln\left(\ln x\right)-1}{\left(\ln x\right)^{\ln x}}dx $$ but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: TeX tip: `\ln x` instead of `lnx` will appear as $\ln x$ instead of $lnx$.

Comment: Were there upper and lower bounds? Wolfram alpha says there is no closed form

Comment: Why there's an "n" ? Where it comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote *"I don't know where to go from here"*. In fact, you are going to nowhere since your problem is still more difficult than the impossible [Somophore dream](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5Bt%5D%28t+Log%5Bt%5D%29%5E2%2Ct%5D).

If you let $x=e^t$, you face the problem of
$$I=\int t^{-t} \,e^t\,dt$$

Even if you expand
$$ t^{-t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{ [t \, \log(t)]^n} {n!}$$ you should face integrals
$$J_n=\int e^t [t \, \log(t)]^n\,dt$$

Just have a look at [the result given by Wolfram Alpha for $J_2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5Bt%5D%28t+Log%5Bt%5D%29%5E2%2Ct%5D).

Now, what you could do is to expand the whole integrand
$$ t^{-t}\,e^t=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac {\big[\log(t)-1\big]^n} {n!} \,t^n$$ and
$$K_n=\int \big[\log(t)-1\big]^n\,t^ n\,dt$$ can easily be integrated.

A small example
$$\int_0^e t^{-t} \,e^t\,dt=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {e^n}{n^n} $$ converges quite fast.